# h2o sparkling: Error reading MOJO JSON: Object not supported:

Tags: python, h2o, sparkling-water

I'm running the Sparkling Water automl example (https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.3/latest-stable/doc/ml/sw_automl.html) on a local spark install on Windows (added code at the top setting up the SparkSession).

My versions:

```
python:3.8.10 (default, May 19 2021, 13:12:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
spark version:3.2.2
pyspark:3.2.2
h2o:3.40.0.2
pysparkling:3.40.0.2-1-3.2
```

When I step-over the line that calls automl.fit(), the training apparently works (details and leaderboard look good), but I get a long series of errors:

```
04-14 19:17:25.105 192.168.0.229:54321   13836    Thread-3 ERROR water.default: Error reading MOJO JSON: Object not supported: 
04-14 19:17:25.105 192.168.0.229:54321   13836    Thread-3 ERROR water.default:  {"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"KeyV3","schema_type":"Key<Keyed>"},"name":"DeepLearning_grid_1_AutoML_1_20230414_191556_model_1","type":"Key<Keyed>","URL":null} 
04-14 19:17:25.107 192.168.0.229:54321   13836    Thread-3 ERROR water.default: Error reading MOJO JSON: Object not supported: 
04-14 19:17:25.107 192.168.0.229:54321   13836    Thread-3 ERROR water.default:  {"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"KeyV3","schema_type":"Key<Keyed>"},"name":"XRT_1_AutoML_1_20230414_191556","type":"Key<Keyed>","URL":null} 
...
```

Has anybody seen this?  Can I safely ignore these errors?